# Array indexing with integers

Tags: c#, arrays, int

I'm trying to get an element from a string array by using an integer for the index number but I keep getting an error:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'

I'd greatly appreciate any help available as I'm quite new to serious programming.

Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/sa91zHWw

```
assetClient.DownloadFile("https://s3-eu-west.amazonaws.com/delvegame/versions/" +versionList[numOfItems]+".txt");
```

Comment: Show us the definition of versionList?

Comment: It looks like `versionList` is an `int`, not an array.

Comment: Post how `versionList` is declared

Comment: `String[] versionList = File.ReadAllLines(runpath + "\\cfg\\versionList.txt");`

Comment: Please use `System.IO.Path.Combine` to combine paths - it's far safer (doesn't work as well for web though as it's an IO function)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you have declared `versionList` as

```
private int versionList;
```

when you intend it to be an array. You should change your definition to

```
private int[] versionList;
```

Answer (score 0):

It really seems like the `versionList` variable is of type `int` and not a `string` array as you described.

This explains why you get this message:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'

Change its declaration to:

```
private int[] versionList;
```

or:

```
private string[] versionList;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfItems; i++)
{
    if (versionDropdown.SelectedIndex == i)
    {
        assetClient.DownloadFile("https://s3-eu-west.amazonaws.com/delvegame/versions/" +versionList[i].ToString()+".txt")
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I had originally defined versionList as a string array:

Comment: `String[] versionList = File.ReadAllLines(runpath + "\\cfg\\versionList.txt");`